# Keep webview always running

Tags: android, webview

I'm searching for a while how to run my WebView forever. When the android function onPause() / onResume() is called. My WebView starts again.

I want the WebView to go on. Maybe the best to explane by an simple HTML example:

```
<html><head><title>Webview test Android</title></head>
<body>
  <h1><div id="counter"></div></h1>
  <script>
   var counter = 0;
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
   setTimeout(function(){ count(); }, 1000);

   function count() {
      counter++;
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
      console.log("counter: " + counter);
      setTimeout(function(){ count(); }, 1000);
   } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want in the app behaviour is:

```
> Open the app
  + Html page starts counting
> Press the home button / multitask button
  + Html page is still counting (or doing other stuff)
> Get back to the app
  + Html page is still counting and dont reload.
```

First I uses my own code for WebView. But with a lot of android versions, I used a chromium-webview [example from github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/jsinterface-example)

I looked into android WebView methods, but I cant figure a solution. I tried also mWebView.onPause(), mWebView.onResume()... With no results. Maybe someone can bring me in the right direction.

This is are the main functions:

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("main"," create ");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new NotificationBindObject(getApplicationContext()), "NotificationBind");
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // use localstorage
    setUpWebViewDefaults(mWebView);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    if(mWebView.getUrl() == null) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
 }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the WebView state (including history stack)
    mWebView.saveState(savedInstanceState);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**Update**

Almost there... I made a Service that runs the WebView.

```
public class TestService extends Service {
    private static WebView w;
    private static MainActivity ma;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {       
            super.onCreate();
    }
    public static void setMain(MainActivity a) {
        ma = a;
        Log.e("main", " setData " );
        setView();
    }

    private static void setView() {
        w = (WebView) ma.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        Log.e("main", " setData ");
        w.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // use localstorage
        w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //ma.setUpWebViewDefaults(w);
        w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("main"," create ");

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);
            TestService.setMain(this);
            MainActivity.this.startService(i);
        } else {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Now when I see the console.log("counter" + counter); logging in Eclipse. The only problem is that the WebView in the layout is gone now when I'm back...

Comment: You'd need to somehow move the webview's event loop to a service, i think.

Comment: Thanks. I googled arround. I found out there are more with the problem... I didnt find a clean solution. But I will try with a service first.

Comment: I used your solution into an app that I am currently developing and I can't for the life of me get it to work. Where you able to use this in production?